# DB Structure for bitcoin blocks

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, database, block

https://github.com/blockchain-etl/bitcoin-etl#schema

I found a library to parse the block data in json format. I want to parse that json and put it into a db to then use that for calculating balances. Is there any smart approach you can recommend me? Im talking about the db tables and maybe if this makes sense? I dont know what the wait times are for queries when it has to check millions of lines

Comment: I can imagine that it would take a long time to check through a table with all transactions, make a where query with the wallet and then calculate the amount that was transfered in and out.